Spring Boot 3.3 with CDS support database error during build process
I am working on a Spring Boot 3.3 project with Java 21 and I am implementing a new CDS (Class Data Sharing) support feature. The application is a standard CRUD application with a REST API that connects to a PostgreSQL database. My application.yml looks like this:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5433/mydatabase
    username: myuser
    password: secret
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
    contexts: schema, data
    database-change-log-lock-table: ${liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table}
    database-change-log-table: ${liquibase.database-change-log-table}
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.show_sql: false
      hibernate.format_sql: true
      hibernate.highlight_sql: true
      hibernate.use_sql_comments: true
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none # validate

audit:
  enable-spring-jpa-listener: true

cache:
  list:
    - name: absence-by-id
      time-to-live: 5m
      enabled: true
  default-time-to-live: 10m
  enable-cache-validation: true

I also have a Dockerfile which is used to build and run the application. The Dockerfile is as follows:
FROM bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-21-crac-cds-musl as builder

WORKDIR /home/app
ADD . /home/app/spring-boot-clean-architecture
RUN cd spring-boot-clean-architecture && ./mvnw -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf clean package

FROM bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-21-cds-slim-musl

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --from=builder /home/app/spring-boot-clean-architecture/target/*.jar app.jar
COPY --from=builder /home/app/spring-boot-clean-architecture/configuration/development/ config/
RUN mv config/application-development.yml config/application.yml
RUN java -Djarmode=tools -jar app.jar extract --layers --launcher

RUN cp -r app/application/* .
RUN cp -r app/dependencies/* .
RUN cp -r app/spring-boot-loader/* .
RUN java -Dspring.aot.enabled=true -XX:ArchiveClassesAtExit=./app/application.jsa -Dspring.context.exit=onRefresh org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.aot.enabled=true -XX:SharedArchiveFile=./app/application.jsa org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher

The Docker build works fine when my PostgreSQL database is running. However, during CI/CD where the database might not be available, the build fails with the following error Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
And the Docker build error:
>>> RUN java -Dspring.aot.enabled=true -XX:ArchiveClassesAtExit=./app/application.jsa -Dspring.context.exit=onRefresh org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c java -Dspring.aot.enabled=true -XX:ArchiveClassesAtExit=./app/application.jsa -Dspring.context.exit=onRefresh org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I am considering the following approaches but am unsure which one is best:

Use a separate application.yml for CI/CD: Configure an H2 database to ensure the application starts without needing a real PostgreSQL instance.
Autoconfigure exclusions: Exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration and JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, but this leads to errors because my repository beans require an entity manager.
3.Any other approach: Is there another way to handle this situation more effectively?

What is the best practice for handling database dependencies during the CI/CD build process to avoid the above errors or to approach Spring Boot with CDS support?

There are some tips for handling external connections during the training run documented here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-lifecycle-smoke-tests/blob/main/README.adoc#training-run-configuration

@Random Guy did you solve this issue?

Yes, I did, docs from Scott helped me, so by using properties in application.yml enabled successful "dry-run" I was looking for. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-lifecycle-smoke-tests/blob/main/README.adoc#training-run-configuration

As Scott mentiond in the comments, there are options for test-run configuration for JPA, JDBC, R2DBC, Spring Batch, Liquibase,... that are documented right here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-lifecycle-smoke-tests/blob/main/README.adoc#training-run-configuration
Using those in my application.yml used for this CDS run established successful run and enabled me to utilize CDS support.
Once again, thanks Scott!

Please share some details like what steps you followed to resolve the issue , which will helpful in future. As links might expired as time flows
